# PyInstaller executable raises ImportError: no module named requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, python-requests, pyinstaller

I'm having a problem creating a standalone executable using PyInstaller. Specifically, when I run pyinstaller -F module_name.py, it creates the executable, but the executable fails with ImportError: no module named requests. The module runs fine through the REPL. I know there's a few other questions out there with ImportErrors using PyInstaller; I've researched them and still can't get it working.

Here's my setup:

- Pycharm 2016.3 on Windows 7 64-bit
- Python 2.7.12 32-bit in a virtual environment
- PyInstaller 3.2

This is a brand-new virtual environment, with the absolute minimum that I need to run this program. Requests and PyInstaller are both freshly installed from pip, and pip confirms that they're both up-to-date.

I've checked my PYTHONPATH, and the path to the virtual environment is in there and correct, and requests is in the virtual environment's site_packages directory. I've tried adding --hiddenimports=requests, no change. I hope I'm not missing something obvious, but I'm about out of ideas.

One thing I have noticed: the warncheck.txt file generated by PyInstaller shows a massive number of missing imports, many of them standard libraries (like re, and functools, and datetime). I don't know if this is a symptom of something else wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I forgot to try last night was to try a different version of PyInstaller. I uninstalled PyInstaller 3.2 and installed PyInstaller 3.1, and the executable now runs perfectly with no problems. I will be reporting the issue to the PyInstaller folks so they can figure out the problem on their end.